# ASP.NET MVC Redirect to action without a physical redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

Are it in any way possible to execute another action in the same on in another controller from an action, action filter or in any other way without doing a physical redirect.

The reason for this is that I have a dynamic paging system, where the user will load  a url, for an example

```
/1/some-page-title
```

This url is maped to the controller “Home” and the action “Element”, this action will then load a row from the database where the element id is “1”. Depending from the data on the element from the database will the page be rendered as a contact form, an image gallery and so on.
Now I could map the paths so

```
/Page/1/some-title/ will render a normal html page,
/Contact/1/some-title/ will render a contact form
/Gallery/1/some-title/ will render a gallery
```

But I would prefer the paths to be simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are problems with this answer, it's been a long time since I did anything thing with ASP MVC, so I'm not actually aware of what the problems are.
Unfortunately I can't delete an accepted answer.
So, I'm striking through the answer as it was, if you can actually answer this, or make it better, please do so.

<s>Yes, very simple really :)</s>

Say you're in controller C action A. You want to "redirect" to controller B action Z, just call the other controller action from the current one, returning it's result.

```
public ActionResult A()
{
    return B.Z()
}
```

Comment: Yes i know this way, but i was hoping for a way to make the system do the redirect for me, so it will fire the filters and execute the injections and so on.

Comment: Ah. No, can't help there, sorry.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this was accepted as an answer and subsequently upvoted, but how has nobody commented on the fact that he's calling an action without instantiating the controller?

Comment: kehrk: I haven't done any ASP MVC in the 3+ years since answering this question, and it's all fallen out of my head (in fact I have no memory of actually answering this question). Thanks for the critique, I'll have a look at this again and update the answer.

Comment: @kehrk: Actually mate if you provide a correct answer for this I'll upvote it and delete my answer.

Comment: maybe return this.Z(); to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [`Html.RenderAction` or `Html.Action`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).  However, these are used in the view and not the controller.